# Entity Framework Core crashes on Linq inside C++/CLI project without giving any error

Tags: c#, visual-c++, dll, entity-framework-core

I have 2 projects in a Solution in Visual Studio 2022:

1. Class Library in .Net 6.0 which is using Entity Framework Core - I tested it with unit tests and it is working flawlessly.
2. Dynamic-Link Library in C++/CLI which is using dll from point 1. I turned on CLR in .NET Core Runtime Support.

Both projects are made in x86.

In my testing project I try to run method from C++ project (point 2) which is using C# dll with Entity Framework (point 1). I can debug it and everything works fine and my DbContext is successfully initialized until it gets to the point of using Entity Framework with any Linq, for example:

```
                bo = (from d in dbConnectionData.pdkContext.Bo_fizs
                  where d.IdOsoby == idOsoby
                  select d).SingleOrDefault();
```

If I go over it it just crashes my test without giving any specific error/exception. And as I said earlier Project 2 works in c# unit test but not here. Do I lack some dlls or maybe I have some bad project configs? I made similiar solution with .net framework instead of .net core and it worked normally inside c++. It is really strange that I don't get any information about what's wrong.
Any idea?